# Download .xls in .aspx and open

Tags: r

I'm trying to download and open an xls file with the code below:

```
library(readxl)

download.file("https://www.cepea.esalq.usp.br/br/indicador/series/boi-gordo.aspx?id=2", "file.xls", mode="wb")

df <- read_excel("file.xls", sheet = 1, skip=3)
```

But returns the error:
`libxls error: Unable to parse file`

Comment: If you just run the download line, do you get an .xls file created?  Can you open it in excel?

Comment: Excel normally opens the downloaded file

Comment: It's timing out (no data returned) for me, that is likely unrelated to your problem though. If you're using a linux-type OS, what does `system("file file.xls")` return? (If windows, try `system("c:/rtools42/usr/bin/file.exe file.xls")`.)

Comment: r2evans, Windows. Returns 127